# ggplot2 stacked barchart with groups

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I want to create a stacked barchart with two stacked columns in each time period.

I was able to achieve it with the code bellow, but the solution has some limitations. Is there other way than using `paste0` for `x` axis? Can I somehow group data by `var4` to achieve it?

```
dd <- data.frame(date = rep(2001:2005,4),
                 var2=rep(c("a","b","c","d"),each=5),
                 var3=rnorm(20,5),
                 var4=rep(c(1,2),each=10))

ggplot(data = dd, aes(x=paste0(date, "/",var4), y=var3, fill=var2)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="stack")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are two options, neither of which is optimal.  The first one uses arithmetic instead of paste, but really is fairly similar to what you are already doing:

```
ggplot(data = dd, aes(x=date + var4/2 - .75, y=var3, fill=var2)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="stack")
```

[image]

The second one uses facets to generate the groups.  This is generic since you can change how many groups `var4` has and this will update automatically.  It is however a total hack:

```
ggplot(data = dd, aes(x=date, y=var3, fill=var2)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="stack") +
  facet_wrap(~ date + var4, scales="free_x", nrow=1) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=dd$date)
```

[image]

Comment: A third option is to facet only by date and have the x axis as `var4`. The x axis won't have dates, but they are at least clearly visible as facet titles that correctly group the bars.

Comment: Thanks, the facet solution is interesting. But yeap, I was hoping that `ggoplot2` can somehow combine `stack` with `position_dodge`.